# Please explain "How Fanboys See .NET Data Access Strategies"

Tags: .net, persistence, culture, data-access

This chart has been linked a number of times on blogs that I follow and I feel like a rube not getting it.  So, going out on a limb here and asking this community.  Please explain this grid from the blog post [here](http://www.kevinwilliampang.com/2010/01/14/how-fanboys-see-net-data-access-strategies/).

[image]

Comment: Why vote to close? The answer to this question has actual, useful info about the relative strengths of these frameworks.

Comment: @JSBangs: I couldn't tell you about the answer, but it was the _question_ that I voted to close, since I didn't see a question there. And another thing: where did this image come from? Are we meant to be answering a question based on some company's marketing campaign?

Comment: Voting to reopen; this question has merit.

Comment: @John, it seems to me that if the *answer* to a question is valid, useful SO content, then the question is valid implicitly.

Comment: Yes, thanks, my question is the relative strenghts and merits of each and why the key merits of one solution would make them perceive the other's in that manner.

Comment: @Lloyd: a picture is worth a thousand words, so start typing. If you _write_ a question, I'll vote to reopen myself. This image is not a question. In fact, if you don't identify where the picture came from, I'm going to flag this question as spam, on the assumption that it's an NHibernate advertisement.

Comment: Well, that's an altogether different question than the one stated above.  Also, it's been asked here a bunch of times.

Comment: @John, Thanks for the critique.  I will do so promptly.

Comment: @Lloyd: thanks. I look forward to seeing the resulting question.

Comment: @John, what is so "advertisey" about this? It's more comical, and singles out no single solution.

Comment: Evidently enough people think it's fine as-is.. so let's have it reopened!

Comment: @mxmissile: I asked that the image should be identified. There was a suggestion that it appeared to be an NHibernate advertisement. If someone says where the image comes from, and it wasn't NHibernate, then fine.

Comment: Vaguely funny grid, but this simple is not a question with programming answers. Vote to close and hope it dies.

Comment: @John, I linked to the blog in the original question.  It's here: http://www.kevinwilliampang.com/2010/01/14/how-fanboys-see-net-data-access-strategies/

Comment: @LLoyd: thanks. I missed that you had a link on the word "here". Do we know where he got it from, or did he create it himself?

Comment: @Lloyd: I was hoping you were going to add a question about relative merits. A question about a picture is not very interesting.

Comment: @John, I did but then it was immediately closed.  Then by the time I had written a longer different question, this one was re-opened.  I figured it would be poor etiquette to post it once this one was re-opened.  Since your note got one upvote too, I may anyway.  Sans image.

Comment: @lloyd: go ahead. It may stay open that way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what the picture means:

**Entity Framework**

- Itself: A polished, professional solution
- NHibernate: For nerds/geeks/open source zealots
- Subsonic: People use this?
- ADO.NET Datasets: Pain in the behind

**NHibernate**

- Entity Framework: Broken and in dire need of repair
- Itself: The holy grail of ORMs
- Subsonic:  Not complex enough, for kiddies (Lego ORM)
- ADO.NET Datasets: Pain in the behind

**Subsonic**

- Entity Framework: Broken and in dire need of repair
- NHibernate: A cluttered mess where you can't find anything
- Itself: Paradise, like a refreshing breeze on a tropical island
- ADO.NET Datasets: Pain in the behind

**ADO.NET Datasets**

- Entity Framework:  What's that?  Never heard of it.
- NHibernate: What's that?  Never heard of it.
- Subsonic: What's that?  Never heard of it.
- Itself: A pain in the behind.

So basically:

- ADO.NET Datasets suck, and are a pain to use, to everybody.
- Someone who uses ADO.NET Datasets is ignorant (has no idea about any alternatives)
- NHibernate and Subsonic users are elitists and/or open source zealots
- Entity Framework users drank too much Microsoft kool-aid and need to have GUIs

Comment: ADO.Net DataSets are a pain to use for objects... but are fine for simple data transfer... then again as most everyone said, DataSets are not object mappers.

Comment: I know many of the pictures were self evident, but the key parts from your answer that helped [me] were Subsonic's view of NHibernate and vice versa. Thanks.

Comment: This is a great example of a good answer to a shaky question. +1

Comment: *"a good answer to a shaky question"* No, a great example of a very good answer with no programming content whatsoever. Which is why the question has no place on SO.

Answer (score 6):

It is showing a graphical representation of how the fans of each solution see the other solutions.

Entity Framework sees Entity Framework as a professional, well groomed, attractive solution. It sees ADO.Net Datasets as a headache. NHibernate sees Entity Framework as an old and broken solution, and itself as the holy grail. Etc.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I understood what the images mean.  But I'd like to know why the key merits of one solution would make them perceive the other's in that manner.  I'll modify my question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a mess up as ADO.NET Datasets are NOT ORM nor where they ever meant to be. 
The rest look to be ORM mappers and I guess the pictures give you an idea of how easy it is to use.